# reassignment/move of std::future waits for existing future to complete

Tags: c++, multithreading, future, rvalue-reference

The main method below launches two `std::async`s.  The future f in the main method is initially used to hold the future for the first async before being reassigned to the future of the second std::async. Both threads still appear to still complete on schedule which surprised me.  Initially I (foolishly?) expected the first thread to be terminated/suspended on the reassignment of the future but was surprised to find it still lingering around.

Based on what I observed today I think I understand that the first async thread becomes detached at the future reassignment.  I kept seeing segfaults during my ordeal today and I reckon this was simply the main thread terminating before the orphaned async processes could finish.

```cpp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#define WAIT_A_MINUTE std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));

int myBusyFunc() {
    WAIT_A_MINUTE
    std::cout<<"done!"<<std::endl;
    return 71675;
}

std::string futureStatusStr(std::future<int>& f){
    switch (f.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0))){
    case std::future_status::ready: return "ready";
    case std::future_status::timeout: return "timeout";
    case std::future_status::deferred: return "deferred";
    default:return "unknown";
    };
}

void printFutureStatus(std::future<int>& f){
    std::cout<<futureStatusStr(f)<<std::endl;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    std::future<int> f = std::async(std::launch::async,myBusyFunc);
    printFutureStatus(f);
    f = std::async(std::launch::async,myBusyFunc);  // waits a minute
    printFutureStatus(f);
    f.wait(); // no wait required - ready
    printFutureStatus(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Additionally, it is noteworthy that the second printFutureStatus(f); statement immediately after the future reassignment doesn't flush immediately. It does appear that the future reassignment causes the main thread to wait. This still surprises me - could anyone offer an explanation?

Comment: **update**: in light of the explanation from @paddy I'm aware of a few incorrect statements in the original question: Firstly, I was incorrect in stating that *"the first future [sic] becomes detached"* but rather the thread object associated with the first future is instead joined. This implicit join was blocking before the second printFutureStatus(f) statement. Secondly, to clarify I only ever saw segfaults in variations of the above code.  Finally, I found "Effective Modern C++ Item 38: Be aware of varying thread handle destructor behavior." to be a good supplement to the final answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is actually documented in [std::future::~future](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/%7Efuture). Excerpt from the documentation below:

> - these actions will not block for the shared state to become ready, except that it may block if all of the following are true:
>
>   - the shared state was created by a call to [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async),
>   - the shared state is not yet ready, and
>   - this was the last reference to the shared state.
>
> In practice, these actions will block only if the task’s launch policy is [std::launch::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch) (see "Effective Modern C++" Item 36), either because that was chosen by the runtime system or because it was specified in the call to [std::async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).

So, you can see that this result is not unexpected. When you reassign `f`, the old object is destroyed and in that process the caller becomes blocked.

Taking the above into consideration, if you need to replace the future without blocking, you have a few options:

1. Use deferred execution policy (`std::launch::deferred`)
2. Store the shared state before replacing: `auto g = f.share();`
3. If you want to discard or "abort" the old async call, introduce a mechanism to signal it for early-out.